# Get id of html element clicked in polymer template

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I wanna  the id of clicked element in html by the function "take this".
I do not understand how to access the html element

```
    <style include="shared-styles">

      :host {
        display: block;
      }

    </style> 

    <div on-click="take_this" id="1">
    </div>

<script>
  class MyView1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
          return 'my-view1';
      }

      takethis() {

      }

}
```

Comment: I solved with: Polymer.dom(e).localTarget.id, in takethis(){}

Comment: even easier: `e.target.id` might work. Anyway, feel free to answer your own question and mark it as accepted answer